# AngularJS - how to call an endpoint in the route resolve?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an AngularJS 1.5.3 project.

There is one page in my app that needs some server information before going to the page. It's kind of like a route guard. No other pages need this information before proceeding.

How can I get this to work in my route resolve? Is this a valid approach to this problem?

e.g.

```
.state('verifyCredentials', {
    url: '/verifyCredentials',
    templateUrl: 'verifyCredentials/verify-credentials.html',
    controller: 'VerifyCredentialsController',
    controllerAs: 'verifyCredentialsController',
    resolve: {

        //calls http request
        authentication
            .getInfo()
            .then(function(response) {
                if(response.goToHome === true) {
                    //$state.go('home);
                } else {
                    //proceed to verify credentials
                }

            })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> An AngularJS (1.x) resolve: block is an object on a state definition. Each key is the name of some data to load, and each value is a function which returns a promise for the data.
>   Resolve functions are injected using Angular’s injector.

An example can be found in the [ui-router tutorial](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem).

You are not providing a valid object to your resolve. The authentication should be a value to a key. Here is how your resolve should look.

```
.state('verifyCredentials', {
    url: '/verifyCredentials',
    templateUrl: 'verifyCredentials/verify-credentials.html',
    controller: 'VerifyCredentialsController',
    controllerAs: 'verifyCredentialsController',
    resolve: {
       authenticate: function(authentication, $state) { // you'll need to inject $state 
 and your authentication service here if you want to use them.
           return authentication
               .getInfo()
               .then(function(response) {
                   if(response.goToHome === true) {
                       $state.go('home');
                   } else {
                    //proceed to verify credentials
                   }

               });
    }
})
```

Another possibility is to use the [`redirectTo`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#redirectto) method on the state object in order to redirect to a different state depending on the resolve.

Use the redirectTo with the resolve like so:

```
.state('verifyCredentials', {
  resolve: {
    authResolve: function(authenticate) {
      return authentication.getInfo();
    }
  },
  redirectTo: (trans) => {
    // getAsync tells the resolve to load
    let resolvePromise = trans.injector().getAsync('authResolve')
    return resolvePromise.then(resolveData => {
      return resolveData.loggedIn === true ? 'home' : null; // go to home if logged in, else stay on this route in order to continue with credentials flow.
    )}
})
```

Here is how the doc recommend to handle resolves. They use component architecture.

```
.state('verifyCredentials', {
    url: '/verifyCredentials',
    component: 'verifyCredentialsComponent',
    resolve: {
       authenticateData: function(authentication, $state) { // you'll need to inject $state 
 and your authentication service here if you want to use them.
           return authentication
               .getInfo()
               .then(function(response) {
                   if(response.goToHome === true) {
                       $state.go('home');
                   } else {
                    //proceed to verify credentials
                   }

               });
    }
})

// component
angular.module('app').component('verifyCredentialsComponent', {
  bindings: {
    authenticateData: '<'
  },
  template: '<div></div>'
  controller: function() {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it and unfortunately the resolve is not being called. Is there something missing?

Comment: Hmm you'll need to return the function in your resolve. I've updated my code example above.

Comment: It's also possible that resolve won't work when using templateUrl/controller properties. ui-router recommends that you adopt a component based architecture. I've added a component example.